# Orthogonal trajectories for a given family of curves

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Find the orthogonal trajectories for the given family of curves:

$$y^2=Cx^3-2$$

Derivative with respect to x, and finding the value of C:

$$2yy' = C3x^2 $$
$$C=\frac{y^2+2}{x^3}$$

Replacing C, and solving for y':

$$2yy' = \frac{3y^2+6}{x}$$
$$y'=\frac{3y^2+6}{2xy}$$

Finding the orthogonal and separating terms:

$$y' = -\frac{2xy}{3y^2+6}$$
$$\frac{(3y^2+6)}{y}y'=-2x$$
$$\frac{(3y^2+6)}{y}dy=-2xdx$$

Integrating:

$$\int{\frac{(3y^2+6)}{y}dy}=\int{-2xdx}$$
$$\frac{3y^2}{2}+6log(y)=-x^2+C$$
$$C=\frac{3y^2}{2}+6log(y)+x^2$$

Was I close? We weren't given solutions, so I'd appreciate a check on my answer. :)

Comment: its a very good explanation . thank you

Answer (score 2):

I've plotted the results on Mathematica and it looks OK.

there's the small detail that the log is missing an absolute value, i.e. it's $6\log |y|$.

Answer (score 1):

That's what I got
$$
y^2=Cx^3-2 \\
2yy'= 3Cx^2 \\
y'=\frac{3Cx^2}{2y}
$$
Orthogonal curve
$$
y'=-\frac {2y}{3Cx^2} \\
\frac {y'}{y} = -\frac 2{3Cx^2} \\
\ln |y| = \frac 2{3Cx} \\
|y| = \exp \left (\frac 2{3Cx} \right)
$$
and here some plots

[image: families]

Comment: The curves don't always look orthogonal, do they? The mistake comes from your handling of  $C$. It is constant on every curve of the original family, but is different from one curve to another. It does not remain constant along  orthogonal curves. This is why the OP eliminated $C$, obtaining an equation of the form $y'=F(x,y)$  before passing to orthogonal family with $y'=-1/F(x,y)$.

Comment: @40votes curves of the same color are orthogonal.