# How can I find the orthogonal trajectories of curves

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How can I find the orthogonal trajectories of the curves 
1) $y^{2}=cx, x^{2}y=c $

and

2) $y=c\sin x$

Answer (score 2):

The key fact is that solutions of ${dy\over dx}=f(x,y)$ will be orthogonal to solutions of ${dy\over dx}=-{1\over f(x,y)}$.

Thus, $y^2=c x\implies 2y{dy\over dx}=c\implies {dy\over dx}={c\over 2y}$. Solving for $c$ in the original equation, $c=y^2/x$. Substituting this into the derivative to eliminate $c$, we obtain ${dy\over dx}={y\over 2x}$. Thus, from the key fact above, the orthogonal trajectories obey ${dy\over dx}={-2x\over y}$. Solve this separable ODE to obtain the implicit family of curves $y^{2}=-2x^2+2K$.

[image]

A similar process will get the other orthogonal trajectories.

Comment: So,at the subquestion 1,do I not have to use the equation $x^{2}y=c$ ??

Comment: Perhaps they want you to find the orthogonal trajectories for the first family and then the second family?

Comment: For the second family,I found $y=\pm \sqrt{x^{2}+c}$ ..Am I right???And how can I continue now??

Comment: Do you understand the first sentence in my answer? If not, concentrate there.

Comment: I don't really understand :/ Could you explain it further to me??

Comment: Study this: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/315317/orthogonal-trajectories-for-a-given-family-of-curves?rq=1

Comment: For $y^{2}=cx$ ,I got $y^{2}=2K-2x^{2} $,and for $x^{2}y=c $ I got $y^{2}=\frac{x^{2}}{2}+M$ .Is this right??What do I have to do now,to complete the first subquestion???